# How to get all products ids from a new order is placed in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
}
```

I got this solution but I think this code is not working in existing woocommerce version. Please help me

Comment: Which version of WooCommerce you use?

Comment: woocommece Version 2.6.14 and wordpress version is 4.7.3

Comment: This code works perfectly, just tested… Where do you use it?

Comment: i use this in functions.php and its shows product name not id . I want id not name .... but id is store in meta value ...so this variable  $product_id = $item['product_id'] is empty